# How to pass param stored in shared preference to retrofit as a parameter for another API

Tags: android, rest, post, retrofit2

i would like to get a user email that's stored in shared preference and use that as a parameter to retrieve specific information from an array in the api..

Process :
After registeration, i store the user info(Email, id and full name) in shared preferences and the user list back end. And in the second Call. i want to use the email alone from shared preferences to retrieve the user settings.
in this case: i would use the email as a search parameter to get the number from this list

This is the list
    {
            "userID": "1",
            "userName": "MyName",
            "email": "mail@gmail.com",
            "phoneNumber": "+1234567"
        }

API.java

```
public interface API {
String BASE_URL = "http://base-url.com/";

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/user/settings")
Call <UserSetModel> getUserSettings(@Field ("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber);
```

UserSetModel.java

```
@SerializedName("userID")
@Expose
private String userID;
....
....
@SerializedName("phoneNumber")
@Expose
private String phoneNumber;
// constuctors
// getter and setters
```

MainActivity.java

```
....
String phoneNumber = "";
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(SampleApi.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

    API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
    Call<UserSetModel> call = api.getUserSettings(phoneNumber);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserSetModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserSetModel> call, Response<UserSetModel> response) {
            response.body();
            try {
                String numb = response.body().getPhoneNumber();
                }catch (Exception e){
                 ....
                @Override
        public void onFailure(
                .....
                 }
```

i don't know how to initiate the email from the user preferences to the post request

EDIT:
UserPreferences.java

```
public void setUserDetails(String Email, String Id, String FullName){
editor.putString(EMAIL_PREF, email)
.....
public String getEmail(String email){}
public String getid(String id){}
....
```

This is set in the signin Class below and is sent to the server

SignIn.Java

```
.....
String email = Edittext.gettext.toString;
String full name = Edittext2.gettext.toString;
....

userPreferences.setUserDetails(email,fullname,id);
Retrofit retrofit .....
```

EDIT: One user is stored in shared preference but all users are stored in the db. so i'm trying to use only the email from (SP) to retrieve the information from the api

Comment: post code where you are saving shared preference

Comment: i just edited that in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

as you want to use only email you have to save it separately to get it back when you need. code to do that will be like below:

```
public final String KEY_EMAIL="user_email";

public String getEmail(){
  return sharedpreferences.getString(KEY_EMAIL,null);
} 
public void setEmail(String email){
  sharedprefEditor.putString(KEY_EMAIL,email);
  sharedprefEditor.commit();
}
```

so when you need to pass it as @Field in retrofit interface call just get it back from sharedpreferences.

This is one way of doing this but I will advice you to make a Model class for your user like **User.java** with **Serialized Fields** and save it as a whole in sharedpreferences with **Gson**.

Link to Gson: [Gson by Google](https://github.com/google/gson)

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

The question is not clear. What you are saving into the sharedpreference ? A particular user or a list of users?

Comment: I just edited it, i'm saving the users details to the shared preference. just one user

Comment: try it. hope it helps